# Button that fills a selected cell when clicked

Tags: excel, button

total noob on VBA and anything that's not a basic macro.

I am trying to create an excel spreadsheet that has a 'list of names' created as 'buttons' where when clicked will automatically fill the 'name' into any selected cell.

I've searched for the last few days and can't find anything that allows me to do this function.  Everything I've tried only works on the cell that I've recorded the macro in.

I can't assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro either.  Essentially, I'd have over 100 'member names' that I want to be able to click at random and have them autofill into say a 'day'.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Happy to learn and try any suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Below is a screen shot of the very basic template that I have.
Ideally, I would like to say click on D5 and the 'click the A.SMITH button' and have A.SMITH appear in D5.

But not always in D5, if that makes sense. I need to be able to select 'team members names' and add them to any day and any shift.

[image]

**EDIT**

Without the VBA knowledge, utilising the 'Insert Controls' in the developer tab, allows me to create the 'command button'.  To allocate a code to this, that would allow me to 'select any cell', would an 'active cell' code be appropriate?

I'm unsure how to incorporate this into the actual spreadsheet.

Currently looks like this;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveCell.Value = A.SMITH
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be beneficial to our understanding to show samples of your data, what you expect to happen and what would be the expected result from this sample.

Comment: Maybe DropDown menues would be a option also, these are simpler in developing. But not so nice to use like buttons.